# react-native run-android installs the wrong project on simulator

Tags: react-native

running:

```
react-native run-android
```

The build goes well and then it tries to install one of the dependencies (react-native-vector-icons) on the simulator instead of the main app:

[image: dependencies]

Comment: Are you sure that command is being run from the root folder of the project?

Comment: yes, i've made sure

Comment: I thought maybe it's a scheme thing because it runs androidTest but not sure where to verify it

Comment: did you try to remove 'build' folder under the android/app folder?